# Default copy constructor and complex inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

If we suppose that we have this hierarchy of classes: A <- B <- C. I have the following questions:

1) If I implement a copy constructor in B, must I call the copy constructor of A in the implementation of B ?

2) Will the default copy constructor of C call the copy constructor that I have implemented in B ?

Comment: Correct answer will no doubt trickle in while I write this comment. Nevertheless I feel like I need to point out that (run-time) polymorphism and copy semantics usually do not fit well, or at all.

Comment: ¤ Re (1), yes you must call it if you want it executed. Otherwise, since you're defining a B copy constructor, it will call the A default constructor automatically, or it won't compile if that call would be ambiguous. Re (2), whether a default copy constructor will call a copy constructor that you have implemented in an immediate base class B, yes /if/ the compiler is able to generate a default copy constructor (i.e. in the circumstances where the question makes sense). Be aware however that e.g. `T(T&)` is also formally a copy constructor... Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Not neccessarily, but it's good practice. It won't be called automatically. You could also call some other constructor (or none, in which case the default constructor is invoked) and do whatever you want, though it is idiomatic to call the base copy constructor.
2. Yes, it will.